# OpenDKIM Unable to bind to port Permission Denied

Tags: dkim

I see a lot of this kind of problem, but with the "Address already in use" error and not the "Permission Denied" error I am getting.

I installed OpenDKIM via this blog:

http://blog.matoski.com/articles/spf-dk-dkim-plesk-debian/

And everything went swimmingly until I restarted Postfix and my log immediately blasts with:

```
OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:8891@localhost: Permission denied
OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:8891@localhost
smfi_opensocket() failed
```

I have verified that nothing else is listening on that port and I have gone back through the blog post and can confirm that everything else is correct.

```
[root@server opendkim]# ps aux | grep opendkim
root     18173  0.0  0.0 103252   864 pts/0    S+   18:39   0:00 grep opendkim
[root@server opendkim]#

[root@server opendkim]# netstat -nlp | grep 8891
[root@server opendkim]#
```

I suspect this is something to do with selinux stopping this from creating another listener, however I do not know how to change that.  Or, perhaps I'm way off base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following command

```
semanage port -a -t milter_port_t -p tcp 8891
```

Comment: Would you mind to give a brief explanation and expected output before I run it?  I'll do some research as well.

Comment: Did some research and ran the command as suggested.  Solved that problem!  Thanks.  I will mark the question as answered.  Unfortunately I have other issues now.

Comment: opendkim can be tricky beast

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to see that.  It is running properly now, however it does not appear to be signing outgoing email.  Sigh.

Comment: If that is the case then the domain is set wrong or mall isn't passing through it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too - turned out to be a typo (on Ubuntu 16 - did not work after upgrade from 14).

I missed the "inet" part of the adress (also given in original question, I just hat "8891@localhost" and not "inet:8891@localohst") from the /etc/default/opendkim. Also, I had the very same setting in the /etc/opendkim.conf before, which seems to be ignored in the new version.